# Saving the ModelForm containing ForeignKey field referenced to another Model in Postgresql database table

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-model-field

Below are my Models

```
class Seminar(models.Model):
seminarID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
presenter_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
location_name = models.TextField()
seminar_DT = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
capacity = models.IntegerField(default=50)

class Registration(models.Model):
registration_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
seminar=models.ForeignKey(Seminar,to_field='seminarID',on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
attendee_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
email_address = models.EmailField()
email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the ModelForm I have created for Registration Model

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Registration
    widgets = {
        "registration_ID": forms.NumberInput(attrs={'required': "required"}),
        "seminar": forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'required': "required"}),
        "attendee_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': "required"}),
        "email_address": forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': "required"}),
        "email_sent": forms.NullBooleanSelect(attrs={'required': "required"}),

    }
    fields = ('seminar','attendee_name','email_address','email_sent')
```

When I run the above RegistrationForm on my Template I get following window

[Image of the Registration ModelForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W11r8.png)

seminar field which is defined as ForeignKey in Registration Model and refers to seminarID in Seminar Model. seminar appears in the registration form pre-populated which is fine but it shows as a Seminar object (2), Seminar object (3)...
Also seminarID in Seminar Model is AutoField and Primarykey as well.

When I save RegistrationForm my postgresql database doesn't get updated with the new values and selected Seminar object (*). Please advise

Both seminar table and registration table snaps are given in these links :
[image of seminar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84dYr.png)
and 
[image of registration table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpykP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `__str__()` method (for Django 3.X) to your Registration class. If you are using Django 2.X add the corresponding method `__unicode__(self)`. Something like the folowing:

> ```
> def __unicode__(self):
>     return "%s (%s)"%(self.presenter_name, datetime.datetime.strftime(self.seminar_DT, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M "))
> ```

This is to tell Django which is the string representation of a Registration object. The information is needed in order to render the object representation into the widget.
Check out also the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#str).